# PyGTK Label emit ButtonPressEvent does nothing and returns False

Tags: python, events, gtk, label, pygtk

Labels can have links by using Pango markup, but the "button-press-event" on a label is not emitted when the label is used in an Expander.  I thought that if I created a subclass of Expander and emitted the "button-press-event" myself, the link would be clicked.  A minimal example of "button-press-event" failing is given below:

```
import gtk 

def on_activate(label, uri):
    print(uri)

def on_click(widget, event):
    label.emit('button-press-event', event)

window = gtk.Window()
expander = gtk.Expander()
window.add(expander)
label = gtk.Label('<a href="google.com">link</a>')
label.set_use_markup(True)
label.connect("activate-link", on_activate)
expander.set_label_widget(label)

expander.connect("button-press-event", on_click)

window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
gtk.mainloop()
```

If I add `print` calls, I can see that `on_click()` is being called, but `on_activate()` is not.  The strange thing is, if I print the returns of `label.emit(...)`, it prints `False`.  What does that mean?  How can I click the link?

Comment: What happens if you try emitting `activate-link` instead of `button-press-event`?

Comment: @oldtechaa: If I use `label.emit("activate-link", "google.com")`, that works fine.  The problem is that I don't have an easy way to find out which url should be emitted.

Comment: The `button-press-event` does not automatically emit an `activate-link` signal as well. To get the URL, couldn't you just retrieve the label's data?

Comment: @oldtechaa: I have figured out a workaround, but I would like to know how I can't mimic the old behavior.  Why does a click activate the link, but the `button-press-event` not?

Comment: The `button-press-event` is triggered when any button on the mouse or keyboard is clicked. If it triggered an `activate-link`, that would mean if you pressed "z" (for example) on your keyboard when the label had focus it would activate the link. That's not exactly the behavior you want.

Comment: Would you like me to post this as an answer?

Comment: @oldtechaa: I would like to know how to mimic exactly the behavior of clicking the link.  Figuring out the url myself isn't ideal.  As for the keyboard presses, I don't believe that is true.  I just did a quick test connecting an `Entry` widget's `button-press-event` to `gtk.main_quit`.  I could type all I wanted into the box and nothing would happen.  If I click in it, however, the main loop stops; the program ends.

Comment: Yes, I was mistaken: the `button-press-event` is only generated with CTRL, ALT, mouse presses, and possibly certain other modifier keys; not sure which. Also, [the docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkLabel.html#GtkLabel-activate-link) say that the second argument passed by the `activate-link` signal is the URI, so you don't have to handle it yourself.

Comment: @oldtechaa: I don't have to handle it in the callback, but if I am emitting the signal, I need to be specific.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110447/discussion-between-oldtechaa-and-zondo).